# Add control dynamically to razor page using C#.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am building a web application using the ASP.NET C# Core 3.1 MVC and Razor pages.

I am new to Razor pages.

I want to add a button dynamically to the razor page through c#.net core backend code.

I have following sample ASP.NET code syntax that adds the html control present in the string "strForm", to the asp page.

```
Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm));
```

What is the equivalent of the above code in C#.NET Core 3.1?

Comment: How dynamic exactly? Do you just need `@if(Model.something){ <button></button> }`? In other words, try to keep your model and view separate. Raw html in your model should be avoided. But all rules are made to be broken...

Comment: Hi @devman, any update here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC doesn't use a control tree; you just need to return the raw HTML to the user:
C#

We have to do the following -
Replace

```
Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm));
```

By

```
return Content(strForm, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
```

Please refer url for reference -

"https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1230430/Unable-to-redirect-user-to-payment-page-of-the-pay"

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core, you cannot target the html and add html to it like ASP.NET by default, but you can use `@Html.Raw(htmlstring)` to display the string to html. And use `ViewData` to dynamically control the html string.

A whole working demo you could follow

Razor Page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel

@if(ViewData["Html"] != null)
{
    @Html.Raw(ViewData["Html"])
}
```

PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel: PageModel
{

    public void OnGet()
    {
        ViewData["Html"] = "<button id=\"btn\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Click</button>";
    }
}
```